# Django redirect not working

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I can see the problem, I attached my code and error page.

In my template, I have:

```
{% if user.get_profile.is_store %}
    <!--DO SOME LOGIC-->
{%endif%}
```

In my view, I have:

```
def downloads(request):
"""
Downloads page, a user facing page for the trade members to downloads POS etc
"""
if not authenticated_user(request):
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/professional/")

if request.user.get_profile().is_store():
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/")

user = request.user
account = user.get_profile()

downloads_list = TradeDownloads.objects.filter(online=1)[:6]
downloads_list[0].get_thumbnail()
data = {}
data['download_list'] = downloads_list

return render_to_response('downloads.html', data, RequestContext(request))
```

Environment:

```
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL: http://localhost:8000/professional/downloads
    Django Version: 1.1.1
    Python Version: 2.6.2
    Installed Applications:
    ['django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.sites',
     'sico.news',
     'sico.store_locator',
     'sico.css_switch',
     'sico.professional',
     'sico.contact',
     'sico.shop',
     'tinymce',
     'captcha']
    Installed Middleware:
    ('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
```

My error report:

```
Traceback:
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
      92.                 response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    File "/var/www/sico/src/sico/../sico/professional/views.py" in downloads
      78.   if request.user.get_profile().is_store():
    File "/var/www/sico/src/sico/../sico/shop/models.py" in is_store
      988.         return not self.account is None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py" in __get__
      191.             rel_obj = self.related.model._base_manager.get(**params)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in get
      120.         return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
      305.                     % self.model._meta.object_name)

    Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /professional/downloads
    Exception Value: Account matching query does not exist.
```

My BaseAccount Class

```
class BaseAccount(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    """
    Return the unicode representation of this customer, which is the user's
    full name, if set, otherwise, the user's username
    """
    fn = self.user.get_full_name()
    if fn:
        return fn
    return self.user.username

def user_name(self):
    """
    Returns the full name of the related user object
    """
    return self.user.get_full_name()

def email(self):
    """
    Return the email address of the related user object
    """
    return self.user.email

def is_store(self):
    return not self.account is None

def is_professional(self):
    return not self.professional is None
```

My Account class`

```
lass Account(BaseAccount):
"""
The account is an extension of the Django user and serves as the profile
object in user.get_profile() for shop purchases and sessions
"""
telephone = models.CharField(max_length=32)
default_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name='billing_account', blank=True, null=True)
security_question = models.ForeignKey(SecurityQuestion)
security_answer = models.CharField(max_length=200)
how_heard = models.CharField("How did you hear about us?", max_length=100)
feedback = models.TextField(blank=True)
opt_in = models.BooleanField("Subscribe to mailing list", help_text="Please tick here if you would like to receive updates from %s" % Site.objects.get_current().name)
temporary = models.BooleanField()

def has_placed_orders(self):
    """
    Returns True if the user has placed at least one order, False otherwise
    """
    return self.order_set.count() > 0

def get_last_order(self):
    """
    Returns the latest order that this customer has placed. If no orders
    have been placed, then None is returned
    """
    try:
        return self.order_set.all().order_by('-date')[0]
    except IndexError:
        return None

def get_currency(self):
    """
    Get the currency for this customer. If global currencies are enabled
    (settings.ENABLE_GLOBAL_CURRENCIES) then this function will return
    the currency related to their default address, otherwise, it returns
    the site default
    """
    if settings.ENABLE_GLOBAL_CURRENCIES:
        return self.default_address.country.currency
    return Currency.get_default_currency()
currency = property(get_currency)

def get_gateway_currency(self):
    """
    Get the currency that an order will be put through protx with. If protx
    currencies are enabled (settings.ENABLE_PROTX_CURRENCIES), then the
    currency will be the same returned by get_currency, otherwise, the
    site default is used
    """
    if settings.ENABLE_PROTX_CURRENCIES and settings.ENABLE_GLOBAL_CURRENCIES:
        return self.currency
    return Currency.get_default_currency()
gateway_currency = property(get_gateway_currency)
```

`

Comment: Have you got both the template tag ({% if...) and the actual downloads view in your template? Please use separate code blocks in your question if these bits are in different places, otherwise it looks very confusing.

Comment: sorry I don't follow, the redirect is in the downloads view and is check that is done as the page is loaded am i wrong?

Comment: That probably is alright then, but it's better if you can separate the code you show into different code blocks, as it looks confusing otherwise.

Comment: How are we supposed to debug this? You don't say what you are expecting to happen. It's quite obvious that the profile `is_store` method is failing. Are you expecting the `authenticated_user` call to redirect away before that can happen? If so, *post the code for that function*. If not, *post the code for the `is_store` function*.

Comment: What I am expecting, is for the user to be redirected to the root of the site, if there are not the correct user type, which is what the is_store method does, the is_store is supposed to determine what user type the user is.  If the user trie to access the page and are a store user they should be redirected.

Comment: Then post the code for `is_store`!

Comment: Your error comes from your flag checking, (as the stack trace tells you), so your problem has nothing to do with redirects.  The trick when debugging django errors is to look for the lines that are actually in your code.  The last one is probably where you need to look for your error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self.account` is pointing at a non-existent `Account` object when it's trying to process `is_store()`.  I would guess you are using a database that doesn't enforce foreign keys *cough*MySQL*cough*, and your data got messed up.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the user.get_profile() return value is empty, and therefore it fails on the next is_store() call:

```
return not self.account is None
```

That fails, because self is empty (i.e. None).

[edit] After reading [this](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter12/) (under Profiles) it looks like the profile for that user does not exist and therefore you get the DoesNotExist exception.

Comment: Except the stack trace shows that the `DoesNotExist` is coming off of the `is_store()` method, not the `get_profile()` method

Comment: @jcd: good point. It would be good if sico87 can post the code of his Account profile object.

Comment: @tomlog, I have enter code have added the class to my original post

Comment: @sico87: where are self.account and self.professional defined? Do they exist in your BaseAccount class?

Comment: Yeah in the BaseAccount class they are the last 2 definitions in that code sample.

Comment: I beleive account is reference to the User model(?) and self.professional is no where to be seen at the moment

Comment: @sico87 -- The stack trace is the long error message that you got.  It's also called the traceback.  If you read it carefully, it will tell you everything that was happening at the time of the error.  The top line was calling the second line, which was calling the third line, and so on.  Some of them are in the django framework, and some are in your code.  The ones that are in your code will tell you where your error happened.  This is not always exactly where your error is, but it's a good place to start looking.

Answer (score 0):

It's not redirect that is not working- it's your is_store() procedure or non-existing profile. You should check what exactly is self.account referring.
As far as I can tell from looking at code, you have two tables in your database- one for baseaccount, which only stores user id, and account, which stores all fields associated with account + baseaccount id. You can try to replace is_store with something like this

```
def is_store(self):
try: 
    return self.account is None 
except Account.DoesNotExist: 
    return False
```

I am by no means an Django expert, but I think this could do the trick.

Comment: Sorry I have inherited this code and I new to Django so I am learning by doing, how see what Account refers to, could I do with do something with ObjectDoesNotExist?